# App is crashing after load images

Tags: objective-c

i'm working on a project with a lot of images but after i load the images (60/70 images) with .xml (thumbnail) the app is crashing. When i only load 30 images the app is working normally.

Does anyone now how i can delay the load of the images? example; first load 10 images and after 5 seconds 10 more?

The .xml is very simply;

```
<images> imagename.png, imagename.png </images>
```

More than 30 images = App crash, less = app working.

Loading the images

```
[DolphiniMages initBook:@"images.xml" curOrientation:curInterfaceOrientation];
```

Comment: I think you may need to clarify why you want to load 70 images at once?  Loading the first 10, then later the next 10 without purging the previous 10 (ad infinitum) simply delays the inevitable memory warning and crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this method in your app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
```

Chances are you're getting a memory warning and ignoring it, so you're being booted by the OS.